# Was ist ‚börmen‘?

Tags: meaning

In Storms »[Schimmelreiter](https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:Storm_Der_Schimmelreiter.djvu/42)« steht von einem Stallknecht:

> Der dicke Mopsbraten hatte die Kälber nicht gebörmt; aber er lag voll getrunken auf dem Heuboden, und das Viehzeug schrie die ganze Nacht...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In den Worterklärungen der Reclam-Ausgabe wird börnen mit **tränken** beschrieben. Der Stallknecht hat den Kälbern also kein Wasser gegeben.

Börnen ist niederdeutsche Mundart und abgesehen von diesem Stück mir noch nie untergekommen. Siehe [Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=qedMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1127&lpg=PA1127&dq=%22b%C3%B6rmen%22%20dialekt&source=bl&ots=4DH3kJ1UEb&sig=FGQNwBP990KyFTw4FZWDQDZkOhg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjntdL-05nYAhVkKpoKHXJ7BMwQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22b%C3%B6rmen%22%20dialekt&f=false)

Comment: Ich denke, das muss es sein. Allerdings steht in meinem Link ‚börmen‘ und nicht ‚börnen‘! Dort kann man die Fraktur sehen.

Comment: @ludi In der mir vorliegenden Reclam-Ausgabe steht "Der dicke Mopsbraten hatte die Kälber nicht gebörnt", also mit n. Merkwürdigerweise steht auch im Projekt Gutenberg die Variante mit m. Ob man das Wort auf verschiedene Art schreiben oder eine ein Druckfehler ist wissen evtl andere. Hier noch ein weiterer Link zu einem anderen Eintrag. Auch mit n. [link](https://books.google.de/books?id=XiZpAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA30&dq="börnen"+dialekt&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWx5LR2pnYAhXoPZoKHXb_DAwQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22b%C3%B6rnen%22%20dialekt&f=false)

Comment: Ich halte "börnen" wegen "Born"=Quelle auch für wahrscheinlicher. Grimm: *BÖRNEN, pecus adaquare, zum brunnen führen, tränken, von born abgeleitet;*

Comment: *pecus adaquare* finde ich einen sehr adaquaten Ausdruck fürs Börnen.

Comment: Welche Reclam Ausgabe? Siehe, bitte, unten.

Comment: @Ludi ISBN: 3-15-006015-X ,Universalbibliothek Nr. 6015 [2], Printed 1991

Answer (score 3):

»Der Schimmelreiter — Reclam XL: Text und Kontext«  (Hsg. Sabine Wolf) verzeichnet im Kommentar:

> gebörmt: (mit Milch) getränkt.

Da es sich hier um eine Quelle handelt, die auch (in Text und Kommentar) das M aufweist, habe ich eine separate Antwort erstellt. Ich konnte gleichwohl bisher keine weiteren Belege für die Existenz dieses Verbs finden (zum Nomen siehe unten). Experten auf dem Gebiet des Niederdeutschen sind nun gefragt!

[Hier](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/t/theodor-storm-der-schimmelreiter--2/6822214) wird die selbe Frage aus dem selben Anlaß erläutert. Es heißt dort, es sei „Niederdeutsch für tränken“. Es fehlt also der Hinweis auf Milch.

Schließlich habe ich noch dieses [Lexikon des Plattdütschen](http://plattmakers.de/de/6708/Borm) gefunden, welches *Börm* und *Borm* in der Bedeutung *Brunnen* aufführt.